# Why is it recommended to prefix property requirements with static in Swift protocols?

Tags: swift

In the [Swift documentation section about Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html), it is written that :

> Always prefix type property requirements with the `static` keyword when you define them in a protocol. This rule pertains even though type property requirements can be prefixed with the `class` or `static` keyword when implemented by a class

I don't understand if you should **always** do that or just in specific cases (because later in the docs, `static` isn't always there).

Why is it recommended to use `static`? What does it mean concretely?

Thank you.

*EDIT : The same question applies to methods requirements.*

Comment: You use `static` in your protocol for "type properties" (i.e. properties associated with the type itself, not particular instances of that type). When `static` is not there, it's not a type property (e.g. a standard stored property).

Comment: Are you asking why you use `static` (as opposed to another keyword) for type property? Or are you asking us what the difference is between an instance property and a type property?

Comment: @Rob Actually I had understood that you should **always** use `static` but now I understand what this `static` means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> later in the docs, static isn't always there

This section talks about *type requirement*, i.e. a requirement of the conforming type to have a `static` property of the specific name and type. In other words, when you write this

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    static var myProperty: Int { get set }
}
```

the conforming class must do this

```
class MyClass : MyProtocol {
    static var myProperty: Int
}// ^^^^^^
```

It also has an option to do this:

```
class MyClass : MyProtocol {
    class var myProperty: Int
}// ^^^^^
```

but there is no such option when defining a protocol.

When `static` is not used, as happens later in the docs, the requirement becomes an *instance requirement*, not a *type requirement*:

```
protocol MyProtocol2 {
   var myProperty2: Int { get set }
}
```

Now the class must provide an instance variable:

```
class MyClass2 : MyProtocol2 {
    var myProperty2: Int
}
```

Note that there is a similar limitation on declaring instance requirements in protocols: you always use `var`, even though an implementation may use `let` to satisfy the requirement:

```
protocol MyProtocol3 {
    var myProperty3: Int { get }
}// ^^^
class MyClass3 : MyProtocol3 {
    let myProperty3 = 42
}// ^^^
```

Comment: Thank you ! I thought it was saying to use `static` always but now I understand the difference ! Thank you so much for this detailed answer.